# Undeclared identifier when calling method from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to call the following method from another class;

```
- (NSString *)findOrCreateDirectory:    (NSSearchPathDirectory)searchPathDirectory inDomain:    (NSSearchPathDomainMask)domainMask appendPathComponent:(NSString   *)appendComponent
                          error:(NSError **)errorOut;
```

calling simple methods before works out well. However, I'm getting a undeclared identifier for 'searchPathDirectory'.
I'm calling it this way;

```
- (void) processDownload:(SKDownload*)download;
{

FileFinder *FFR = [[FileFinder alloc] init];

[FFR findOrCreateDirectory :searchPathDirectory inDomain:domainMask     appendPathComponent:appendComponent error:errorOut];

}
```

Where FileFinder is the class holding the method I'm calling. Could someone please explain why i'm getting this error and suggest a solution. I've tried making this a class method but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You need to pass actual values for each parameter when you call the method. This is Objective-C 101.

Comment: BTW, it should be `error:&errorOut`.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. Though i'm still stuck on the appendPath. I get;     - (NSString *)findOrCreateDirectory:        (NSSearchPathDirectory)searchPathDirectory inDomain:        (NSSearchPathDomainMask)domainMask appendPathComponent:(NSString       *)appendComponent
                              error:(NSError **)errorOut;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass actual values. NSSearchPathDirectory and NSSearchPathDomainMask are enum types. Look at NSSearchPathUtilities in foundation to see all possible values. Following is an example -

```
    [vc findOrCreateDirectory:NSUserDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appendPathComponent:@"app" error:nil];
```

Comment: I did that but i've now gone down a different route successfully to move my downloaded files into the ApplicationSupportDirectory. Thanks to all who replied! Disappointed some felt it necessary to down vote me as I'm new to this and trying to understand Objective-c.